# Java LinkedList wont print variable from object when using .next().get

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to print a string variable from my object Song which is stored in a LinkedList. But every time I use .next().getTitle it tells me I have a null pointer exception. I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

Adding songs is conditional that it must exist in an album. Then I extract it. I know ArrayList is different from LinkedList

I only posted parts of the code I thought were relevant

This is my first time posting

edit: I added the Song class and Album class and inputs I made in the main class

Song class

```
public class Song {
private String title;
String duration;

public Song(String title, String duration) {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getTitle() {
    System.out.println(this.title);
    return this.title;
}

public String getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
```

Album class:

```
public class Album {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Song> songs;

public Album(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
}

public ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
    return songs;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public boolean addSong(String name, String duration){
   if(isSongOnFile(name)){
       return false;
   } else{
       Song newSong = new Song(name, duration);
       this.songs.add(newSong);
       return true;
   }

}

private boolean isSongOnFile(String name){
    for(int i=0;i<this.songs.size();i++){
        if(this.songs.get(i).getTitle().matches(name)){
            return true;
        }
    } return false;
}
```

Playlist class:

```
private String name;
private LinkedList<Song> myPlayList;
private ArrayList<Album> myAlbums;

public PlayList(String name) {

    this.name = name;
    this.myPlayList = new LinkedList<Song>();
    this.myAlbums = new ArrayList<Album>();
}

public void addSong(String songName){

        Song foundSong = getSong(songName);
        this.myPlayList.add(foundSong);

}

public Song getSong(String songName){
    for(int i=0;i<myAlbums.size();i++){
        ArrayList<Song> albumSongs = myAlbums.get(i).getSongs();
        for(int j=0;j<albumSongs.size();j++){
            if(albumSongs.get(j).getTitle().matches(songName)){
                return albumSongs.get(i);
            }
        }
    } return null;
}


public void printSongList(){
   
    Iterator<Song> i = this.myPlayList.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next().getTitle());

    }
}
```

Here is the code tested in main

```
    PlayList myPlaylist = new PlayList("vol3");
    Album starLordVol1 = new Album("vol1");
    Album starLordVol2 = new Album("vol2");
    starLordVol1.addSong("cherry bomb", "03:46");
    starLordVol1.addSong("get your love", "02:52");
    starLordVol2.addSong("pop", "04:10");
    starLordVol2.addSong("whatever", "03:54");

    myPlaylist.addAlbum("vol1");
    myPlaylist.addAlbum("vol2");
    myPlaylist.printAlbumList();

    myPlaylist.addSong("cherry bomb");
    myPlaylist.addSong("pop");

    myPlaylist.printSongList();
```

I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at PlayList.printSongList(PlayList.java:81)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: can you post your Song class?

Comment: Hi there, please add the code that can reproduce the problem :)

Comment: I added the song class and other classes involved and my attempts to test out the code in main

Comment: Where do you add the Album to your PlayList? I would guess, that getSong(....) always return null because no album exists in the list. You add just a String ("vol1") but not the object it self.

Comment: What does `addAlbum()` method look like? You've skipped it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that it is possible to add `null` values to  `LinkedList`. Your implementation of `getSong` returns `null` when the song is not found in album.  Then, in `addSong` you add that returned value to your `myPlayList`. You don't really want to do that. All you need to do here is to check if the value is null just before adding it to the list:

```
public void addSong(String songName){
    Song foundSong = getSong(songName);
    if(foundSong != null){
        this.myPlayList.add(foundSong);
    }
}
```

Comment: I test it in main and make sure the songs exist because I make them first. Then I try to add them to the playlist. So it should not return null

Comment: @AlexVasconcelosdeAlmeida If that is not the case then there is nothing else in the code you provided that could cause a NPE.